# ApplePay PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController always shows processing

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

[image] I am trying to use Apple Pay in my app. It works fine to present PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController. However, after I filled up with credit card and billing information, it just shows a spinning wheel and 'processing' as shown in the picture.

The code for presenting Apple Pay view controller is as follows:

```
let request = Stripe.paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier(DH_APPLEPAY_ID)
request.paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: label, amount: amountDecimal)]

request.requiredBillingAddressFields = PKAddressField.All
request.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressField.PostalAddress | PKAddressField.Email
request.countryCode = "US"
request.currencyCode = "USD"
request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.CapabilityEMV | PKMerchantCapability.Capability3DS
request.supportedNetworks = [PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa]

if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(request) {

    let paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)

    paymentController.delegate = self

    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(paymentController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    //popup
    DHUtils.alert("Apple Pay", message: "Please add your credit card to Passbook.", inViewController: self)
}
```

The `func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment!, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)!)` delegate never get called.

The certificate status looks all right. What do I miss here to make it work?

Comment: Are you seeing the "Processing" message before you touch ID / enter a passcode? Did you implement any other delegate methods for the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`, such as `didSelectShippingAddress`?

Comment: @lxt I implemented didSelectShippingAddress.   I commented it and the "Pay with Passcode" shows up.   I guess I have done sth wrong in didSelectShippingAddress.   Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: No problem! Perhaps you weren't calling the completion handler in that delegate method?

Comment: @lxt You saved me another day. Thx :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be a completion block that you need to call. It should be in the delegate method **didAuthorizePayment** on the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, you need to use this completion block and pass the success or failure message to it. It should look somewhat like this

```
extension BuySwagViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
  func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment!, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)!) {
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success)
  }

  func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Here in completion block you should pass PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success or 
PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Failure depending on whether you were able to process the payment.

Also, you can refer the Ray Wenderlich tutorial here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/87300/apple-pay-tutorial

Answer (score 5):

My issue was having this delegate method:

```
func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didSelectPaymentMethod paymentMethod: PKPaymentMethod, completion: ([PKPaymentSummaryItem]) -> Void) {

}
```

Remove it and it should stop the endless spinning.

Comment: Yes, this was my case as well.

Comment: Had the same issue., so strange

Answer (score 0):

You are able to see processing UI if you use next `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` method **without** calling `completion`

```
func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didSelect paymentMethod: PKPaymentMethod, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate) -> Void)
```

To fix it just call `completion`:

```
extension SomeViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
    public func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didSelect paymentMethod: PKPaymentMethod, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate) -> Void) {
        //as an example
        let paymentMethodUpdate = PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate(paymentSummaryItems: [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "someLabel", amount: 0.01)
        ])
        completion(paymentMethodUpdate)
    }
}
```

As you can see here you have `PKPaymentMethod` which actually provides you `PKPaymentMethodType` (Credit, Debit...) all others variable will be `nil` at this moment. They are will be filled when you authorize(`didAuthorizePayment`) - `PKPayment.PKPaymentToken.PKPaymentMethod`

Please note that it is a place for extra logic that is why use it when you need it for reaching your goals. It means if you don't need this extra logic just remove this method