# For ApplePay paymentAuthorizationViewController delegate creates nil PKSummaryItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments, applepay, passkit

In reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239635/applepay-pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-always-shows-processing/29411804?noredirect=1#comment46997958_29411804), thank you for narrowing it down. But sadly I have to configure this delegate

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
               didSelectShippingMethod:(PKShippingMethod *)shippingMethod                   
completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus, NSArray *summaryItems))completion
{
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess, [self summaryItemsForShippingMethod:shippingMethod]);
}

- (NSArray *)summaryItemsForShippingMethod:(PKShippingMethod *)shippingMethod
{
    totalPrice = 5;
    NSString *prices = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalPrice];
    NSDecimalNumber *num = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:prices];
    PKPaymentSummaryItem *foodItem = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Total Products Cost" amount:num];
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [foodItem.amount decimalNumberByAdding:shippingMethod.amount];
    PKPaymentSummaryItem *totalItem = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Video Mantis Productions, INC." amount:total];
    return @[foodItem, shippingMethod, totalItem];
}
```

in order to show the user what products summary really is. Sadly I am getting **PKPaymentSummaryItem *foodItem** as nil and consequently the processing doesn't ever gets fixed. Please HELP! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer, eh? I was using **Stripe** as an intermediate medium for transactions with **ApplePay** and hence used their **SDK** and tutorials to setUp **ApplePay** as well. Anyhow, the **Passkit's** **PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController** uses two separate protocols that can be configured in order to help ease up the implementation. I was using both, namely;

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didSelectShippingMethod:(PKShippingMethod *)shippingMethod
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status, NSArray *summaryItems))completion;
```

And...

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                  didSelectShippingAddress:(ABRecordRef)address
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status, NSArray *shippingMethods, NSArray *summaryItems))completion;
```

However, what I noticed was when the later one was called, that is, **didSelectShippingAddress**, the **Passkit** kind of stalled, so I removed it and only used the first one that is **didSelectShippingMethod** to help implement the entire thing, and the infinite processing never occurred again! Hope it works out for you too (:

Answer (score 0):

PKPaymentSummaryItem is available from iOS 8, so if you are trying to use it with a less recent iOS version, you'll get nil instead of expected value.

I just got stuck with this too

Comment: Naah! Using iOS8 man! Btw I figured out that it'll remain the same. But does the "Processing" on Apple Pay go away?

Comment: Can you try creating your PKPAymentSummaryItem with this ?

    NSDecimal decimalAmount = [@(totalPrice) decimalValue];
    NSDecimalNumber *amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:decimalAmount];
    PKPaymentSummaryItem *summaryItem = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Total Products Cost" amount:amount];